# How to copy a public variable use go?

Tags: go

How to copy a public variable use go?

For example, a public variadble named PublicVar

```
a := []string{"A", "B"}
b := a
fmt.Printf("%v\n", a)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", b)

b[0] = "C"
fmt.Printf("%v\n", a)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", b)
// a has been changed.
```

The PublicVar's name will be changed, but this is not what I want.

I just want to copy the value of PublicVar.

Comment: `temp := PublicVar` **does** copy the value and does nothing else. It is impossible to "change the name" of a variable in Go (exported or unexported). What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Volker actually temp := PublicVar does not copy the value always. For example if PublicVar is referring a slice or a channel or a map, then temp also will be referring to the same copy of the data.

Comment: @Nipun Thats because slices channels and maps are reference types. Not because `:=` behaves differently. It does always copy the *value*. In case of slices, channels and maps the value is a reference.

Comment: @AH Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen because probably `PublicVar` is a pointer to an instance. So `temp` is also pointing to the same instance. You can get a value type by following.

```
temp := *PublicVar
temp.name = "bob"
```

See an example at [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lmEsuhTOsz)

**Edit**: Since the question is edited to show the variable of concern is a slice, khrm's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562171/1150725) is more relevant.

Comment: Among the stuffs I miss in Go are constructors, copy constructors, assignment operators that are almost always used in C++. The confusions and dangers that we see in the example is much lesser in C++.

Comment: I want to copy value of slice not reference, what is correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Go copy by value. But in case of maps and slices, there is an exceptions in that only their reference is copied as they are implemented as reference type.

In case of slice, you can do this using builtin copy:

```
b := make([]string, len(a))
copy(b,a)
```

In case of maps:

```
for k, v := range a {
    b[k] = v
}
```